# Conexão mysql dentro de uma classe

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, classes

Olá, estou com bastante dificuldades em realização uma conexão com o banco dados. Para realizar a conexão eu criei uma classe chamada `Conexao` e estou usando PDO, quando preciso fazer um select, por exemplo, faço a chamada da classe de conexão dentro da classe `Credenciais` que possui o método `PegaCredenciais`, onde será feito o select.

Quando realizo a instancia da classe `Credenciais` dentro do arquivo **Classes/Credenciais.php**, onde ela está, funciona perfeitamente. Más quando a instancia é feita no arquivo **index.php**, eu recebo erro 500 ao carregar a página e só resolve o erro quando retiro a classe `Conexao` de dentro do método `PegaCredenciais`.

Já fiz testes e a classe de seleção é visível no arquivo **index.php**, estou usando o Composer.

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Classes\Credenciais;

$credenciais = new Credenciais();
$credenciais->PegaCredenciais();
```

**Classes/Credenciais.php**

```
namespace Classes;
    
class Conexao{
     private static function connect(){
        return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meu_banco", "meu_banco", "root");
     }
}

class Credenciais{
    public function PegaCredenciais(){
        $db = Conexao::connect();
        $dados = $db->query("SELECT * FROM credenciais WHERE id = '1'");
        $dados = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $dados->token;
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
         "Classes\\":"Classes/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema. A classe PDO não estava sendo localizada, para usa `namespace` preciso inserir uma barra ao contrario antes de definir PDO.

**Ex:**

`$dados->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`